# how tell Thunderbird to open links in a certain Firefox instance?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

I'm using Firefox and Thunderbird profiles for different activities and have them running as separated instances (processes) on different virtual desktops.

This works great in general. But a big issue is that I can't directly open links from mails. I just get the message "Firefox is already running, but is not responding..."

Is there a way to configure the url handler such that it will open the site in a Firefox instance with a certain profile? 
I already tried to set the preference 
*network.protocol-handler.app.http* to */usr/bin/firefox -P myprofile* , but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix at the link below. The additional instructions in comment #4 were necessary for me and hopefully will make it work for you.

http://hsmak.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/howto-force-thunderbird-to-open-links-in-firefox/

Comment: Welcome to AU!  Instead of just posting a link, it's more helpful to actually write out the directions and include a link as a reference.

Comment: that's what I already tried

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the answer to this and eventually found the following working solution:

In thunderbird set network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http (and network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https and network.protocol-handler.warn-external.ftp) to true. This  causes Thunderbird to ask for an application when you try to open a link.

For the URL handler, instead of calling firefox directly, use a script where MOZ_NO_REMOTE is unset, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset MOZ_NO_REMOTE
exec /usr/bin/firefox $1
```

(from http://forums-test.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=756575&start=0)